# Is the Lenovo U430 Touch Model a 64 bit or 32 bit processor?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, 64-bit, disk-cloning

Is the Lenovo model U430 touchscreen come with a 32 or a 64 bit processor?

Comment: What processor does it have? How old is it? If it is less than 20 years old then chances are it is 64-bit.

Answer (score 3):

The specifications for the Lenovo U430 Touch Ultrabook are available [on the Lenovo web site here](https://www.lenovo.com/ee/et/laptops/lenovo/u-series/u430-touch/). All the models use 4th gen Intel processors from the [i3-4010U](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/75107/intel-core-i34010u-processor-3m-cache-1-70-ghz/specifications.html) up to the [i7-4510U](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/81015/intel-core-i74510u-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-10-ghz/specifications.html) and these are all 64 bit processors.